# Javacript on button to update a field on OLI

Tags: javascript

On a button click on parent object, i need to update a field in child object. I have tried to work out the below code,which if modified for parent works fine. But the moment I change it to work for the child object. It doesnt give the expected update.

```
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")} 

if('{!Opportunity.HasOpportunityLineItem}' == true){
window.parent.location.href="/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?&clone=1&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}&cloneli=1";

var update_Opp2 = [];
var oOpp2= new sforce.SObject("OpportunityLineItem");
  oOpp2.OpportunityId ='{!Opportunity.Id}'
oOpp2.check__c = true;
update_Opp2.push(oOpp2);
result_Update=sforce.connection.update(update_Opp2);
window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query for the child records that you want to update:

```
var oliQuery = "Select Id, OTHERFIELDS From OpportunityLineItem Where OpportunityID = '{!Opportunity.Id}' ";

var oliResult = sforce.connection.query(oliQuery);
var oliRecords = oliResult.getArray("records");

if(oliRecords.length > 0){
   //Do what you need to with the records
}else{
  //there was an error querying for the records or none was returned
}
```

Then update them

Comment: Thanks Eric,Worked. What would you recommend to newbies like me,who want to learn to use javascript with salesforce?

Comment: @user10727 - for this specific topic, review the AJAX toolkit - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/ for other topics visit developer.salesforce.com

Comment: how can i debug these codes? I tried it by using sforce.debug.open(); but it opens a page as shown below 'Ajax toolkit shell' : and doesnt make sense to any variable in the code.                                                                                                          AJAX Toolkit ShellFeatures: autocompon of propert with Tab, multiline input with Shift+Enter, input history with Up/DownValues and functions: ans, print(string), props(object), blink(node), clear(), oad(scriptURL), scope(object)Using bookmarklet version of shell: commands will run in opener's context.